# jQuery make checkbox checked on select's selected option

Tags: jquery

I want to make a checkbox to be "checked" upon changing a `<select>` where the selected `<option>`'s value is the value of the to-be-selected checkbox. Example: If I select 'dyst2' from `#id_dystrybutor_glowny`, I want the checkbox with value '2' to be checked.

I prepared fiddle but can't make it work:
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3UP3a/169/)

```
<select id="id_dystrybutor_glowny">
<option value="1">Dyst1</option>
<option value="2">Dyst2</option>
<option value="3">Dyst3</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" class="dystrybutor" value="1"> Dyst1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="dystrybutor" value="2"> Dyst2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="dystrybutor" value="3"> Dyst3<br/>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#id_dystrybutor_glowny').change(function () {
    var dID = $(this).find(":selected").val();         
    if $('.dystrybutor').attr( "value" ) == dID {
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
    };
  });     
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.dystrybutor[value="' + dID + '"]').prop('checked', true)
    .siblings().prop('checked', false);
```

working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jajs6kqh/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution:

All you have to do is, filter the checkbox based on the selected value and apply the checked property.

Steps:

1. Remove previously selected values
2. Find the matching checkbox based on value in 'select' control
3. Apply the checked value for the checkbox

https://jsfiddle.net/3UP3a/170/

**Code:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#id_dystrybutor_glowny').change(function () {
         var dID = $(this).find(":selected").val();  

         $('.dystrybutor').prop('checked', false).filter(function(){
             return this.value === dID;
         }).prop('checked', true);
     });     
 });
```